# Invalid product redirects to index.php?controller=404

Tags: php, .htaccess, prestashop

when I type invalid product url in prestashop, deleting ".html" from the end of the url. Instead of showing me 404 page with the same url it gives me a 302 redirect to "/index.php?controller=404".

How to make it to just show me 404 page instead of redirecting, I only have this problem with products, in categories and other parts of the shop 404 page works fine.

I tried turning on and off friendlyURL but problem still persists.
Here's the link to the [website](https://ogrod-pro.pl/) and here's example of [redirection](https://ogrod-pro.pl/1347-kosiarka-spalinowa-weibang-wb537sc-v-al)(it's just product url but without ".html" at the end)

Comment: but it is working exactly the same as in other parts of the store, PrestaShop always redirects to 404 if Dispatcher cannot find a proper way to send user

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I just had to find the place where the code was sending me  to controller 404, then I took from github copy of the same page from the same presta version and inserted it instead of previous content, not it's working.